# Using axios to fetch data from an API which has an API attribute in it in react

Tags: reactjs, axios

Im using react to fetch data from starwars api(https://swapi.co/). It has a homeworld attribute which calls a futher api for fetching the details about homeworld. I've tried using axios.get() inside another axios.get() to fetch the details for **`"${results.homeworld}"`** (PFA code), but it doesnt return anything. Not sure why is this happening and even i cant update state even though i change the axios.get request. It's set to my first search i.e Luke skywalker. What should i do for changing state with every request and how to handle the homeworld API inside the inital JSON object.Also i get an error of **Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0** , did try online help for that but still the same problem.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Axiosa extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { data: {}, name: "", homeplanet: "", species: "" };
  }



    fetchStarwars() {
        axios
          .get("https://swapi.co/api/people/3/")
          //.then(results => results.text())
          .then(results => results.json())

          .then(results => {
            let x = `"${results.homeworld}"`;

            console.log(`"${results.homeworld}"`);

            axios
              .get(x)
              .then(resultshomeworld => {
                resultshomeworld.json();
                console.log(resultshomeworld);
              })

              .then(results => {
                this.setState({ homeplanet: results.name });
              });

            this.setState({ data: results, name: results.name, isLoading: false });
          });
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchStarwars();
      }

      render() {
        console.log(this.state.homeplanet);
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <span>{this.state.name}</span>
            <div>{this.state.homeplanet}</div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Axiosa;
```

Comment: You haven't returned `resultshomeworld.json();` and hence the next, .then won't have the correct promise to execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H have made some changes in your code. You need `this` in `fetchStarwars` function, which could be fulfilled via `bind` as Nitha said, or using arrow function.

See the working sample [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cxvoxp)

```js
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import {render} from "react-dom"

class Axiosa extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { data: {}, name: "", homeplanet: "", species: "" };
  }



    fetchStarwars = () => {
        axios
          .get("https://swapi.co/api/people/3/")
          .then(response => {
            let results = response.data
            let x = results.homeworld;

            this.setState({ data: results, name: results.name, isLoading: false });
            return axios.get(x)
          })

              .then(results => {
                this.setState({ homeplanet: results.data.name });           });
        
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchStarwars();
      }

      render() {
        console.log(this.state);
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <span>{this.state.name}</span>
            <div>{this.state.homeplanet}</div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }


render(<Axiosa />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Hi,i have a doubt,what if i have to return more than one parameter. like you've returned **return axios.get(x)** but what if i've to return the species type too which also requires an api call. what should i do.?

Comment: You can use `Promise.all`or `axios.all` for that purpose. You should provide an array of multiple `axios.get` or any other promise to one of `Promise.all` or `axios.all` and you will receive an array of responses in the next `then` clause.

Comment: Take a look at last example [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#example).

Comment: that helped actually,it returned an array of responses.

Answer (score 0):

Bind fetchStarwars function inside the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: {}, name: "", homeplanet: "", species: "" };
    this.fetchStarwars = this.fetchStarwars.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: Hi Nitha, It still shows the same output as lukeskywalker and the homeworld api is still not fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing all the stuff from your second `then` block within the first one, or have the first `return Promise.resolve(result.json());` so it can access the reduced promise value.

Do the same thing with the nested second axios call.

```
fetchStarwars() {
    axios.get("https://swapi.co/api/people/3/")
      .then(result => {
          let results = result.json();
          let x = `"${results.homeworld}"`;

          console.log(`"${results.homeworld}"`);

          axios.get(x)
              .then(results => {
            this.setState({ homeplanet: results.json().name });
          });

          this.setState({
              data: results,
              name: results.json().name,
              isLoading: false
          });
      });
  }
```

Also, make sure to also bind `this` to `fetchStarwars` within the constructor.